# Excel Conditional Formatting if contains Partial Text/Character

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

My first hurdle is that I need for a cell to receive a fill color if it contains a Question Mark, ?, even if it contains other text.  So whether a cell contains a ?, Y?, ?No - it fills the cell yellow.  I've tried quite a few variations including using wild cards with no success.  Closest I've come is;

```
Formula:=SEARCH("?",U11)
```

or

```
Formula:=SEARCH("*?*",U11)
```

but they both have the same result of highlighting / filling the cell no matter what is entered.

2nd objective is for it to fill the cell IF it contains a "?" or some other special character like an asterisk.  Since I can't get the 1st to work, I haven't attempted an OR statement.

Comment: `=FIND("?",U11)`

Comment: =SEARCH("~?",U11)

Comment: Used FIND and it worked great.  Thanks!  Tried the SEARCH with ~ and it worked as well.  Appreciate your time.

Comment: Shall I make it an answer? Will you accept it if I do?

Comment: Yes, please make it the answer.  Do OR statements work the same with conditional formatting?  So if I want the cell highlighted IF "?" OR "*".

Comment: I tried =OR(FIND("?",U11),FIND("*",U11)) but it acts as an AND statement.  The cell doesn't highlight unless both characters are included like ?* or *?.

Comment: Yes, OR() can work... but you need to handle errors. See my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
=OR( IFERROR(FIND("?",U11),0), IFERROR(FIND("*",U11),0) )
```

Or a little cleaner...

```
=IFERROR(FIND("?",U11),0)  +  IFERROR(FIND("*",U11),0)
```